# Should we have to do this everytime like- install main and dev dependencies and configuring babel,webpack and npm scripts?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, nodemon, npm-scripts

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem. I want to create a new react project then every time Will I have to follow the whole guide like - installing main dependencies ,installing dev dependencies and configuring babel,webpack and npm scripts or Is there any workaround so that I can use dependencies installed and configured in another project in my new project as both the projects are present in my local machine or PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to follow these steps

1. npx or npm create-react-app my-app
2. cd my-app
3. npm start

Comment: This is the answer. Create react app is maintained alongside react and hides all of that boilerplate configuration (babel/webpack/etc) so you can focus on developing your react app instead of configuring all that stuff.
If you ever need to expose that configuration, you can run `npm run eject` and it will be moved in to your source.
In the majority of production apps I've worked on, though, there's never been a reason to eject.  https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html